# Responsive menu won't pop up

Tags: javascript, html, css

my code is here

https://codepen.io/bunea-andrei/pen/ZEeeWPK

I'm talking about the mobile view of the website , please make the screen smaller until it changes to the stance I'm referring to

I assume it's something wrong with my JavaScript code and I spent the last 3 hours trying to figure out what is it

Code is here

```js
const wrapperSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
    const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

    burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
        wrapper.classList.toggle("wrapper-active");

        burger.classList.toggle("toggle");

        });
    }

wrapperSlide();
```

```css
/*   top side with the logo and info    */

top{
    height:140px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    display:block;
}

    top .left-side {
        margin-left: 450px;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
    }

    top .left-side li{
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        line-height:1.2em;
    }

    top .right-side {
        margin-right:450px;
        text-align: left;
        padding-top: 30px;
        float:right;
    }

    top li{
        list-style: none;
        line-height:1.1em;
    }



/*   navigation menu    */
menu {
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    height: 90px;
    border-bottom: 22px solid red;
}

    menu .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around; /*play with the width and padding to split out the categories more*/
        width: 50%;
        padding: 10px 485px;
    }

menu .line{      /* the separation lines between the categories */
    width:1px;
    height:70px;
    background:grey;  
}


    menu span {    /*  editing the writing of the menu bar*/
        color: white;
        font-size: 25px; 
         margin-top: 30px;  
    }
    
       menu span a:link {  /* removing the underline and set a color for the link to change it from blue*/
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
        }

       menu span a:visited{  /* makes the color of the links stay the same after clicking  */
           color:inherit;
       }

    menu .box {        /* creating the box in which i will put each item of the menu*/
        width: 180px;
        height: 70px;        
        text-align:center;
        line-height:65px;
    }

    menu .box:hover {
        background-color: green;
    }

   menu .burger div{
        width:25px;
        height:3px;
        display:none;
        background-color: #97903f;
    }



    @media only screen and (max-width: 415px) {

        menu {
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom: none;
            max-height: 35px;
            margin-top: -170px; /* to reverse the top with the menu*/
            padding-top: 15px; /* to move the burger lines a bit down from the top of th menu */
            background-color: rgb(35 22 68 / 0.94);
        }

    
            menu .burger div { /* editing the burger lines */
                display: flex;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                margin-left: 15px;
            }


        top {
            margin-top: 30px; /* to get it further down from the top so i can replace it with the menu */
        }

            top .left-side {
                margin-left: 10px;
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
            }

            top .right-side {
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-top: -40px;
                margin-right: 70px;
            }


        menu .wrapper {
            margin-top: -207px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 569px;
            padding:0px;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: rebeccapurple;
            padding-left: 20px;
            transform: translateX(-100%);
            transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
        }

        menu .line{   /* modify the separation line from vertical display to horizontal */
            height:1px;
            width:220px;
            margin-left:-20px;
        }


        .wrapper-active {
            transform: translateX(0%);
        }



        .toggle .line1 {
            transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
        }

        .toggle .line2 {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .toggle .line3 {
            transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
        }


            }
```

```html
 <top>
        
        <div class="left-side">
            <ul>
                <li style="font-size:50px; color:#0094ff; letter-spacing: 4px; ">ROXIRALU</li>
                <li>DERATIZEZ TOT CE MISCA VERISORU' TE PUP</li>
                <li>SPECIALIST xD</li>
            </ul>     
        </div>
        
        <div class="right-side">
             <ul>
                <li style="font-size:25px; color:#000000; letter-spacing:1px; font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif; padding-bottom:2px;">Suna 08763575321</li>
                <li>Luni-Vineri 12:00-24:00</li>
                <li>Sambata-Duminica INCHIS</li>
                <li>Da-mi email la: sagunu@salam.hd</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
       
    </top>

  <menu>

       <div class="burger">
          <div class="line1"></div>
          <div class="line2"></div>
          <div class="line3"></div>
      </div>

      
     <div class="wrapper">
        
             <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="box">
              <span>
              <a href="#">Soareci</a>
              </span>
    </div>
        
          <div class="line"></div>
     <div class="box">
              <span>
              <a href="#">Gaze</a>
              </span>
    </div>      
    
          <div class="line"></div>
     <div class="box">
              <span>
              <a href="#">Fantome</a>
              </span>
    </div>
    
          <div class="line"></div>
     <div class="box">
              <span>
              <a href="#">Purici</a>
              </span>
    </div>
          
          <div class="line"></div>
           <div class="box">
              <span>
              <a href="#">Otravuri</a>
              </span>
    </div>
          
          <div class="line"></div>
           <div class="box">
              <span>
              <a href="#">Cozonaci</a>
              </span>
    </div>
          
          <div class="line"></div>
           <div class="box">
              <span>
              <a href="#">Prafuri</a>
              </span>
    </div>
          
          <div class="line"></div>
           <div class="box">
              <span>
              <a href="#">Contact</a>
              </span>
    </div>
          <div class="line"></div>

             </div>
      
    
  </menu>


 <script src="js/index.js"></script> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specificity for the selector `.wrapper-active` that is applying the transform to show the navigation has a lower specificity value than `menu .wrapper`, which is also defining a transform. This is causing the `transform: translateX(-100%);` to take over.

Adding more specificity to the active class should do the trick:

```
.wrapper.wrapper-active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, does this example work for you: https://codepen.io/tiffachoo/pen/a156004d8accdd9d2b9080134f02c942?editors=0110 ? It has the more specific selector implemented and seems to work on my end.

Comment: Thank you so much i forgot to add the dot before the wrapper class . you made my day thank you

Comment: I just realised that i've actually typed it like this in the first place .wrapper  .wrapper-active{  transform: translateX(0);  } and it didn't have any effect . do you know why's that ? it doesn't make any sense to me , normally I leave a space between the 2 classes and it always worked fine

Comment: No prob! :D When we add a space between elements in a CSS selector, this looks for a parent element with any child element. (ie. <div class="wrapper><div class="wrapper-active"></div></div>). When we don't add a space between classes, this looks for these classes on the same element (ie. <div class="wrapper wrapper-active"></div>). In this case, we needed to look for an element with both the .wrapper and .wrapper-active classes!

Comment: That's a very good explanation thank you so much. I'm stuck on the last adjustment i have to do to the menu. I managed to animate the opacity of the links but i can't make them pop up from left to right . Here's my code again: https://codepen.io/bunea-andrei/pen/ZEeeWPK . Do you have any idea why ? Don't worry if you don't have the time to answer this , you've already did so much for me .